# Enable IAM authorization on HTTP API Gateway from CDK

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

When creating a route in an HTTP (not REST) API Gateway API, I'm [able to require IAM authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-access-control-iam.html) from either the console or the CLI.

I can't figure out how to do this from CDK. The `authorizer` parameter wants an [`IHttpRouteAuthorizer`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigatewayv2.IHttpRouteAuthorizer.html), and the only implementations I see are `HttpJwtAuthorizer`, `HttpLambdaAuthorizer`, `HttpUserPoolAuthorizer`, `HttpNoneAuthorizer`, none of which seem to correspond to simple IAM authorization.

What do I need to do to configure a route to use IAM authorization from CDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP API is still experimental in CDK. Not all features are there yet.

That said, the `HttpIamAuthorizer` is [under development](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/17519) at the moment and is very close to getting merged.

**Update** (26 Dec 2021): `HttpIamAuthorizer` is now available from versions 1.137.0 and 2.3.0 on.

Comment: As [jeff-robbins pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70551615/2016290), it's not in 2.3.0 but will hopefully be in 2.4.0.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the previous post (I am new, and lack the reputation points to comment directly)

> Update (26 Dec 2021): HttpIamAuthorizer is now available from versions 1.137.0 and 2.3.0 on.

Unfortunately, something went wrong with the CDK release mechanism.  See https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18138 for details.  `HttpIamAuthorizer` is not available in version 2.3.0.

Comment: Update (10 Jan 2022): CDK v2.4.0 (and now v2.5.0) added `HttpIamAuthorizer` support.